# Wordpress: displaying 25 posts from one category and 55 from another

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm trying to make a loop that will get the latest 25 posts from one category and the latest 55 from another, they need to be in the same loop and the posts are in a isotope filtering system and when it is on 'all' it needs to display all the categories in date order not category type>post date, is there a trick for doing this?

Thanks, Harry.

EDIT:
Here is what I currently have for my get_posts loop;

```
            <?php
            global $post;
            $myposts = get_posts('cat=10,11,49&numberposts=50');
            foreach($myposts as $post) :
            setup_postdata($post);
            $cat_name = '';
            $category = get_the_category();
            $cat_name = $category[0]->slug;
            ?>


            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I have tried a few logical things such as;

```
            $myposts = get_posts('cat=10,49&numberposts=50', 'cat=11&numberposts=50');
```

But this just returned posts from category 10 and 49.

I thought maybe something like this could work but need the right syntax for it;

```
      $myposts11 = get_posts('cat=11&numberposts=50');
      $myposts1049 = get_posts('cat=10,49&numberposts=50');
      $myposts = $myposts1049 + $myposts11;
```

Comment: please show your code anything you tried ...

Comment: I don't think WordPress's `WP_Query();` could handle this directly. You would probably have to loop through the posts indefinitely (`while ( has_post(); && $count1 <= 25 && $count2 <= 55 )` as an inexact amount of posts would need to be checked till you found all you needed). $count1 and $count2 you would need to implement yourself.

Comment: What about if I used get_posts? Would that handle better do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with what you've tried is you've added two post arrays together as if they were numbers;

```
 $myposts = $myposts1049 + $myposts11;
```

You should be using `array_merge` to merge the two arrays into a single array and loop through that instead;

```
 $myposts = array_merge( $myposts1049, $myposts11 );
```

EDIT

Looking at the Wordpress StackExchange site, Otto has answered a very similar question here;

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130009/how-to-merge-two-queries-together#answer-130055

And additionally used `array_unique` to eliminate duplicates before using the new array in a `WP_Query` object.

Comment: Thanks for this, I just managed to get it working before I read your answer so didn't get a chance to test it out. if you can confirm this will work I'll happily mark it as an answer, else I'll post the thread where I found my answer and mark that one, your call!

Comment: Hi Harry, no worries and glad you got it sorted.  That's totally up to you of course :)  I've edited the answer to flesh it out and link to a pretty good thread on the WP Stack on the same thing.  Cheers.#

Comment: Well you have been thrurough with your answer with external reference links, I'll set this as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I'll also leave this here, which is what gave me my answer, very similar to what you posted but many resources is always usefull for future readers - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/multiple-queries-compiling-into-one-loop?replies=5#post-1920638

Comment: Nice one - you're right, more links and reasoning turns it into a useful SO resource.  Cheers!